# Element not visible error, I tried all Xpath ,css selector, id, class and name also but nothing work. i tried previous solution but still not solve

Tags: automated-tests

I tried all `Xpath`, `css selector`, `id`, `class`, and `name` also, but nothing works. I tried previous solution but it did not solve the problem:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Frontend {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriverlatest.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://genba.online");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='en-btn']")).click();//translate to english language
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/a[2]")).click();//click on access button
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='email']")).sendKeys("a@b.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='password']")).sendKeys("123456");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='rememberme']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='user_detail']/div[2]/div[2]/button")).click();

    }

}
```

Comment: Could you please add a bit more detail to your question?

Comment: yes, in this site after opening the url we have to click on access button to enter the user id and password. My script successfully open the url and click on the language change button and then on the access button. then one div pop up that ask for email id and password but my script not able to locate that element . if i am avoid that code and try to click on submit button script work but email id and password text box not visible to selenium.